# Returning value from a window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is javascript code in the .aspx page.

Can the `window.opener.document.getElementById()` be used to return values from a pop up window that is opened using `window.open('http://popupwindow.aspx)`? This is working fine when the I run the app. from Visual Studio. However when I run the app. using the URL (example: http:\h09999\Testapp)it does not work. 
How can I pass the value back to a control in the calling window?

Comment: you can use showModalDialog() instead of window.open(), allowing you to set window.returnValue in the popup before close()ing it, returning the value to the showModalDialog call much like prompt() or confirm().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't work as expected due to the complexity of the popup window

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [sample](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) to find out how to pass values between the open window and the caller...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript variable in the parent window.

```
var retValue = "";
```

Then in the child window you can set the parent value before closing the window.

```
parent.retValue = "Some value Returned.";
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener.document` is proper way of returning value from open window to the caller. Surely there is some glitch with the hidden field you are trying to access through getElementById. Try running your code with error console (in FireFox) open and see what error message you are getting.

Example Link:
http://forums.aspfree.com/html-javascript-css-help-7/open-javascript-window-return-value-parent-208178.html